# Multiple jQuery gets in parrallel using the async/await pattern

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I want to access three api methods in parallel using jQuery and the async/await pattern in Javascript. The results of the three calls should be written into a Knockout Observable. I created the following code:

```
await Promise.all([
    (async() => vm.allHaulers(await $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompleteHaulerList')))(),
    (async() => vm.allPlants(await $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompletePlantList')))(),
    (async() => vm.allTrailers(await $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompleteTrailerList')))()
]);
```

This looks very bulky with all the brackets. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use .then of the Promise returned by $.get

```
await Promise.all([
    $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompleteHaulerList').then(vm.allHaulers),
    $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompletePlantList').then(vm.allPlants),
    $.get(baseAddress + 'GetCompleteTrailerList').then(vm.allTrailers)
]);
```

Sometimes the "old" tools work better :p

Comment: That's why I love StackOverflow. But woudn't it be better to use `done` instead of `then`?

Comment: When using Promises, I prefer to use Promise/A+ specified methods @AndréReichelt